# Redirect from my local weblogic server to server with static content

Tags: weblogic

I have a .war with static content that contains js frameworks like jquery, extjs.

Actually we have separate static content server for it. But when work with local server it is not available.

I don't want to deploy this .war with static content to local server.

Is there are any way to make redirect from my local weblogic server to server with static content?